# Hola necesit0 hacer un programa en C++ dudas

Tags: c++, while

Necesito hacer un menú en el que el usuario debe elegir una opción del menú.

No se saldrá del menú hasta que el usuario seleccione salir (opcion de salir).

Tiene que ser con la función while

Comment: Cada vez la gente se molesta aun menos en escribir su pregunta... madre mía. A ver, prueba a empezar leyendo [ask] y haz el [tour]. Luego, editas tu pregunta, añades el código de lo que hayas hecho, nos indicas dónde está el error que tengas y ahí seguro que alguien te ayuda. Pero llegar aquí, ponernos una *orden* y esperar a que lo hagamos por ti, ***desde luego no va a dar el resultado que esperas***. Si quieres aprender a programar, tendrás que hacerlo *** programando tu***, no copiando y pegando código de otros hombre! Esta pregunta no cumple ninguna regla y acabará cerrada. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

No te voy a hacer el código porque pienso que así no aprendes tú. Pero te dejo el razonamiento para que puedas hacerlo tú:

1.Utiliza la sentencia do while( es mejor que while en estos casos). Se saldrá del while si opcion==valordesalida. Supon que quieres salir del bucle si el usuario inserta 0, pues seria: do{}while(opcion!=0);
2.Creas una variable opcion que se la pides al usuario dentro del do while.
3.Realizas un switch(opcion) y segun el valor insertado realizas alguna cosa.
4.Usa el caso default para poner algun mensaje de error, porque sería un valor no valido.

Espero haberte ayudado,un saludo.